# AG-Grid skip column on export to CSV

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have a column in a table which has only buttons in it. The button is a download button. I dont what this column to be exported when i click on export to csv. Can this be done?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but this is what worked for me:

```
exportToExcel() {
var params = {
    columnKeys: ['FIELDA', 'FIELDB', 'FIELDC']
};
this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
}
```

You get the fields from the ColumnDef

Answer (score 3):

You can specify which columns data you want in export while calling `gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params)`. You can mention that in `columnKeys` parameter.

```
params.columnKeys = ["country", "bronze"];
this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
```

Reference: [ag-grid: CSV export](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#example-csv-export)

Check the result - if you check `Specify Columns` checkbox, only the above mentioned columns will be there in the CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Internally it search for colId of a particular column. AG Grid adds '_1' to every field as a unique colId.

Try this , It will work.

Under ColDefs , if your field name is : FieldA , FieldB.

```
const params = {
columnKeys: ['FieldA_1','FieldB_1'];
};
```